# Adding items into database

Tags: java, javafx

I want to add data into my database but i constantly get errors and i cant find a solution for my problem online.

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;

public class vrachtwagentoevoegencontroller {
    public Button backbtn;
    public Button toevoegbtn;
    public TextField txtmodel;
    public TextField txtinhoud;
    public TextField txtaantal;

    public vrachtwagentoevoegencontroller() throws SQLException {
    }


    public void back(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
        Parent root2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("VrachtwagenBeheer.fxml"));
        Stage stage1 = new Stage();
        stage1.setTitle("Vrachtwagen Beheer");
        stage1.setScene(new Scene(root2));
        stage1.show();
        Stage stage = (Stage) backbtn.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/dorb_logistics", "root", "jorisDJ1");
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    int rs = 0;

    public void add(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        String model = txtmodel.getText();
        String inhoud = txtinhoud.getText();
        String aantal = txtaantal.getText();

        String sql = "INSERT INTO vrachtwagens (Model, Inhoud, Aantal) VALUES ('"+model+"' and '"+inhoud+"' and '"+aantal+"');";



        try {
            preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = preparedStatement.executeUpdate(sql);
            txtmodel.setText("");
            txtinhoud.setText("");
            txtaantal.setText("");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

this is what i have so far, everytime i trie to use executeUpdate it wants me to use an int, but when i do that it says that the column row count does not match the value of 1 or something like this. can someone please help me with this problem? this is the error: java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: please specify code with `executeUpdate` and exact error

Comment: first of all, if you get an exception it would be helpful if you add it to your question, otherwise it hard to help you. 

the datamodel of the table you want to insert your data into would also be helpful. 

also if you are executing sql directly, ommit the last semicolon in your query

Comment: It would help if you provided the exact error/stacktrace and the DDL of the `vrachtwagens` table.

Comment: the error i constantly get is java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1, and i changed the code in my question to what it is when i use executeUpdate

Comment: the values in "values" should be separated by comma, not "and"

Comment: @sharonBenAsher i have tried that already but that doesn't work

Comment: and I recommend using bind variables, so you are not exposed to sql injection

Comment: if i may ask, what are bind variables?

Answer (score 2):

First, your query is not correctly writen. Values in an insert query are comma separated :

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO vrachtwagens (Model, Inhoud, Aantal) VALUES ('"+model+"', '"+inhoud+"', '"+aantal+"');";
```

Then, you need to use the `PreparedStatement` correctly, without passing the query in `executeUpdate`. Or you just use a `Statement`.

```
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

And since you are "using" a `PreparedStatement`, you should really not concatenate the values but use arguments and set the value safely and prevent SQL Injections.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO vrachtwagens (Model, Inhoud, Aantal) VALUES (?, ?, ?);";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, model);
ps.setString(2, inhoud);
ps.setString(3, aantal);

ps.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use executeUpdate for insert/update commands since executeQuery expects a resultSet which is not the case here.

reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)

Comment: The OP has modified the question. It no longer uses `executeQuery`, but `executeUpdate`. Even though this is a partial answer for the initial question, it no longer addresses any issue in the current version of the question.